# terraform code for picking auto scaling group

Tags: terraform-provider-aws, aws-application-load-balancer

We have 2 terraform scripts -ec2 creation (maintained by one team) and alb creation (maintained by our team). d
ec2 is created with 1:1:1 asg and each instance has its own asg.
When creating the alb, I am attaching the auto scaling group to target group.
So if I have 2 ec2 instances both of them will have 2 asg but both of them will point to the same target group. When I translate this to terraform, I have this

```
data "aws_autoscaling_groups" "asg_servername" {

 filter {
  name = "tag:Name"
 values = [var.ec2[0]]
 }
}
data "aws_autoscaling_groups" "asg_servername1" {
filter {
  name = "tag:Name"
 values =  [var.ec2[1]]
}
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_attachment" "alb_server1_http" {
  autoscaling_group_name = data.aws_autoscaling_groups.asg_servername.names[0]
  lb_target_group_arn   = aws_lb_target_group.tg-fss.arn
}
resource "aws_autoscaling_attachment" "alb_server2_http" {
  autoscaling_group_name = data.aws_autoscaling_groups.asg_servername1.names[0]
  lb_target_group_arn   = aws_lb_target_group.tg-fss.arn
}
```

So I have to define 2 resources for getting the asg name and another 2 resources for attaching these asg to same target group.
I am trying to see if this can be made generic (if there are 10 ec2 instances, it would look ugly to have 20 resources all of them trying to kind of doing same thing)

Request for guidance.